# SQLite battery consumption - android

Tags: android, sqlite

i've been looking around and couldn't get a clear answer for this one:
How high is the battery consumption if i am using a sqlLite database in my app?
Specifically i have about 500 writes and 500 reads every minute or so.. does it cause
a lot of battery usage?

Thanks in advance!
Omri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say "how much" battery it'll use, but it definitely won't be good for your battery performance. It'll take some battery juice, that's for sure.

Comment: Ok thanks! i'll try to implement a solution with less DB accesses